# How to get mutable slice with conditions in Rust

Tags: rust

I'd like to write something similar with following code in Rust.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<i64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut s: Vec<&mut i64> = v
        .iter_mut()
        .filter(|val| **val < 2_i64)
        .collect();
    if s.len() == 0 {
        s = v
            .iter_mut()
            .filter(|val| **val > 2_i64)
            .collect();
    }
    *s[0] = 0;
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

It's obviously making borrowing reference twice. I know it causes an error, `E0384: cannot assign twice to immutable variable s cannot assign twice to immutable variable`.

Could you tell me how to write this kind of work flow in Rust? I want to filter value and if it returns nothing, apply another filter and get `Vec` of borrowing reference.

I tried to use shared reference. After filtered the `Vec`, I needed to convert shared reference to borrowing one, but it was not possible.

Comment: Are you sure you want mutable reference to `i64`s? You could create a new vector with numbers directly

Comment: What do you want to do with `v` afterwards? The solution somewhat depends on it.

Comment: Actually, I'm implementing `Vec` of `struct`. But for making it easy, I'm using `i64`. And I want to change fields of struct after applying the filter.

Comment: Why don't u use a `for`?

Comment: Because I needed to know the array had elements or not. I needed two loop. Thank you very much for the answer. It's what I would like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like that. I agree that it's not really beautiful, but it works:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1_i64, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let s: Vec<_> = v.iter_mut().filter(|&val| *val < 2).collect();
    let mut s = if s.len() == 0 {
        v.iter_mut().filter(|&val| *val > 2).collect()
    } else {
        s
    };

    *s[0] = 0;
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Comment: `|&&mut val| val < 2`

Comment: I'm not sure about which is better to use `|&&val|`, `|&val|` or `|val|`. Could you leave your opinion here?

Answer (score 0):

We can clone the reference like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<i64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut t = v.clone();
    let mut s: Vec<&mut i64> = v.iter_mut().filter(|val| **val < 2_i64).collect();
    if s.len() == 0 {
        s = t.iter_mut().filter(|val| **val > 2_i64).collect();
    }
    *s[0] = 0;
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Comment: You should avoid cloning as long as you can.

Comment: @fx-kirin Not to counter but clone will loose the reference after the main .So why should we avoid using it .Can you please explain

Comment: for memory efficiency.